# Referential integrity constraint violation on remove with @OneToMany

Tags: rest, jpa, hql

I'm not able to delete an 'Adresse' that has 'personen' referenced in the Database. I get a Referential integrity constraint violation on 'personen' . 
I want to delete an 'Adresse' and their 'personen' when calling em.remove(adresse).
What do i have to do, to accomplish this, without having to remove the referenced 'Person' first?

*Important Code parts:*

**Model**

Adresse

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ADR_PK")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "adresse", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<PersonDetail2> personen;
```

PersonDetail2

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ADR_FK", referencedColumnName = "ADR_PK", nullable = false)
private Adresse adresse;
```

**Service**

Persistance

```
public Adresse deleteAdresseWithId(Integer id) throws DetailException {
    List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();

    Adresse adresse = em.find(Adresse.class, id);
    if (adresse == null) {
        throw new DetailException(errorMessages, Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);

    }
    log.debug("adresse found " + adresse.toString());
    em.remove(adresse);
    return adresse;

}
```

**Test**

Rest

```
@HttpTest(method = Method.POST, path = "persDB/rest/r/deleteAdresse/3", content = "{}",    type = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void deleteAdresseFound() {
    Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
2014-01-27 11:17:43,312   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] FINE  org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher - PathInfo: r/deleteAdresse/1
2014-01-27 11:17:43,312   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] FINE  org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector - Beans found for class ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersRestService : [Managed Bean [class ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersRestService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,313   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersJPA - delete adresse with id: 1
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Opened session at timestamp: 13908178633
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl - Skipping JTA sync registration due to auto join checking
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl - successfully registered Synchronization
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Looking for a JTA transaction to join
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.jboss.as.jpa - http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1:[transaction scoped EntityManager]: created entity manager session TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffa609125d:-2eb1ffe2:52e62875:ba status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.jboss.as.jpa - http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1:[transaction scoped EntityManager]: reuse entity manager session already in tx TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffa609125d:-2eb1ffe2:52e62875:ba status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Loading entity: [ch.saxer.persDB.model.Adresse#1]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
2014-01-27 11:17:43,314   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool - java:jboss/datasources/persDBds: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@105d5aa[userName=root]) [1/20]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,315   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
2014-01-27 11:17:43,315   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        adresse0_.ADR_PK as ADR1_18_0_,
        adresse0_.ort as ort18_0_,
        adresse0_.plz as plz18_0_ 
    from
        Adresse adresse0_ 
    where
        adresse0_.ADR_PK=?
2014-01-27 11:17:43,315   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[ch.saxer.persDB.model.Adresse#1]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [ch.saxer.persDB.model.Adresse#1]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [ch.saxer.persDB.model.Adresse#1]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext - Initializing non-lazy collections
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Done entity load
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersJPA - adresse found Adresse [id=1, plz=1234, ort=ort1]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,316   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.jboss.as.jpa - http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1:[transaction scoped EntityManager]: reuse entity manager session already in tx TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffa609125d:-2eb1ffe2:52e62875:ba status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections - Collection dereferenced: [ch.saxer.persDB.model.Adresse.personen#1]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 1 deletions to 1 objects
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 1 removals to 1 collections
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ch.saxer.persDB.model.Adresse{id=1, personen=<uninitialized>, plz=1234, ort=ort1}
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
2014-01-27 11:17:43,317   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
2014-01-27 11:17:43,318   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    delete 
    from
        Adresse 
    where
        ADR_PK=?
2014-01-27 11:17:43,319   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK8E488775F35C0145: PUBLIC.PERSON FOREIGN KEY(ADR_FK) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ADRESSE(ADR_PK) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from Adresse where ADR_PK=? [23503-171] [n/a]: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK8E488775F35C0145: PUBLIC.PERSON FOREIGN KEY(ADR_FK) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ADRESSE(ADR_PK) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from Adresse where ADR_PK=? [23503-171]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:414)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:431)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:307)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:873)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:890)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:99)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:75)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:334)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:568) [h2-1.3.171.jar:1.3.171]
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:181) [h2-1.3.171.jar:1.3.171]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:156) [h2-1.3.171.jar:1.3.171]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:142) [h2-1.3.171.jar:1.3.171]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3134) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3337) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:100) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

 etc.

2014-01-27 11:17:43,325   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
2014-01-27 11:17:43,325   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK8E488775F35C0145: PUBLIC.PERSON FOREIGN KEY(ADR_FK) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ADRESSE(ADR_PK) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from Adresse where ADR_PK=? [23503-171]
2014-01-27 11:17:43,325   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Skipping aggressive release due to registered resources
2014-01-27 11:17:43,325   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Mark transaction for rollback
2014-01-27 11:17:43,325   [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] WARN  com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffa609125d:-2eb1ffe2:52e62875:bb, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@191b93e >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK8E488775F35C0145: PUBLIC.PERSON FOREIGN KEY(ADR_FK) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ADRESSE(ADR_PK) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from Adresse where ADR_PK=? [23503-171]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1372) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1301) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1495) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:91) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:231) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:303) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:189) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:42) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:176) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at ch.saxer.persDB.interf.PersJPAInterface$$$view3.deleteAdresseWithId(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:110) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersJPAInterface$-1484255507$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.deleteAdresseWithId(PersJPAInterface$-1484255507$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java) [classes:]
    at ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersService.deleteAdresseWithId(PersService.java:64) [classes:]
    at ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersRestService.deleteAdresseWithId(PersRestService.java:159) [classes:]
    at ch.saxer.persDB.service.PersRestService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deleteAdresseWithId(PersRestService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jet-jboss-web-custom-eap-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK8E488775F35C0145: PUBLIC.PERSON FOREIGN KEY(ADR_FK) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ADRESSE(ADR_PK) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from Adresse where ADR_PK=? [23503-171]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3134) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3337) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:100) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:280) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.3.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK8E488775F35C0145: PUBLIC.PERSON FOREIGN KEY(ADR_FK) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ADRESSE(ADR_PK) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from Adresse where ADR_PK=? [23503-171]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:414)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:431)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:307)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:873)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:890)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:99)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:75)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:334)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


etc.
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: JPA requires the provider to cascade the remove to the referenced PersonDetail2 objects within the personen collection.  For that to work though, this collection must contain all PersonDetail2 entities that reference the address - make sure that you have been maintaining both sides of your relationship - check this collection when you are about to delete to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: @Chris thx. but sadly, this isn't the Problem. 'Adresse.Personen' contains all referenced PersonenDetail2 objects.

Comment: Then if PersonenDetail2 objects are not being deleted first you have a JPA provider bug, or you have a PersonenDetail2 entity that is not listed still referencing the Addresse you are trying to remove.  Check that you have not removed any from the collection by querying for all PersonenDetail2's referencing your addresse directly and comparing the two collections.  Also check that there aren't other references to PersonenDetail2  in your model that might prevent them from being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris Thanks, this was the problem. I had two Person Entities for the same Table Person (PersonDetail1 / PersonDetail2). When i chose Adresse referencing PersonDetail2 to delete, it didn't have the referenced Table from PersonDetail1. So i programmed a third Class Named PersonDetail3 that referenced all Tables. Changed Adresse to reference PersonDetail3 instead of PersonDetail2 and programmed AdressDetail2 that referenced PersonDetail2. And now it works without any problems.